# How to change the type in the ajax

Tags: django

```
template.html
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {          


var a="{{parameter}}";

    $.ajax({
    type :'GET',

    url : geturl(a),

    dataType : 'json',


views.py
if param=="daywise":

    print request.method
    if request.method=="POST":


        if request.POST.get('monyrsubmit'):
            monthform=MonthForm(request.POST)
            if monthform.is_valid():
                selected_month=monthform.cleaned_data["Month"]
                selected_year=monthform.cleaned_data["Year"]
                print selected_month
                print selected_year
```

im actually doin a post method by sending a form data. but its taking it has a get request since i have given the type has GET in the ajax script. im doing a check in the views. if request.method=="POST" but this method remains GET

Comment: What's the problem? Maybe change `type :'GET',` to `type :'POST',`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to POST...

```
var a="{{parameter}}";

    $.ajax({
    type :'POST',

    url : geturl(a),

    dataType : 'json',
```

If you didnt disabled the CSRF middleware in django, it will cause a problem.
to fix it, add this script right after the `<script>` tag and before `$(document).read...`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                     // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                     if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                     }
                 }
             }
             return cookieValue;
         }
         if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
             // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
         }
     } 
 });
```

Comment: i want to have a GET as well as POST request. GET to load sumthin default and then POST is when i want to retrieve teh data based on wat data i send through the form

Comment: You will need to seperate the calls